# How to convert list of key-value pairs to list of string (key,value)

Tags: c#, list, key-value

I have a list of key-value pairs.

```cs
var y = this.Request.Cookies.ToList();
```

which would have multiple `Key="Key",Value="value"` pairs.

This has to be converted to a List of string => `"key","Value"` pairs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you _just_ want a readable string representation and don't care about the exact format, `ToString()` will give you "[key, value]". So, `y.Select(kvp => kvp.ToString()).ToList()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Work with `.Select()` from `System.Linq` to convert Key-Value pair to string.

```cs
using System.Linq;

Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "Key1", "Value1" },
    { "Key2", "Value2" },
    { "Key3", "Value3" }
};
        
List<string> result = dict
    .Select(x => $"{x.Key},{x.Value}")
    .ToList();
```

[Sample program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/80XkHs)